# How to set Termset on managed metadata field in XML?

Tags: managed-metadata, term-set

I am building some VS SharePoint solution. I have a feature which provision columns and a content type. One of the columns is a managed metadata field. I would like to set the Termset on this managed metadata column. How to that?

```
<Field ID="{0AF6E300-E338-440F-90CB-726C11028EE1}"
       Name="MyCompanyDocTypeTaxHTField0"
       DisplayName="MyCompanyDocType_0"
       Type="Note"
       Required="FALSE"
       ShowInViewForms="FALSE"
       Hidden="TRUE"
       CanToggleHidden="TRUE"
       RowOrdinal="0" />

  <Field ID="{F46BBB43-3E95-4AAA-A1AA-47EBC6B7DD0B}"
         Name="MyCompanyDocType"
         DisplayName="Documenttype"
         Type="TaxonomyFieldType"
         ShowField="Term1033"
         Required="TRUE"
         Group="MyCompany"
         >
    <Customization>
      <ArrayOfProperty>
        <Property>
          <Name>TextField</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q6="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                 p4:type="q6:string"
                 xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">{0AF6E300-E338-440F-90CB-726C11028EE1}</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
          <Name>IsPathRendered</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q7="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q7:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">true</Value>
        </Property>
      </ArrayOfProperty>
    </Customization>
  </Field>
```

Comment: Are you referring to add an instance to the list or to the definition of the column as linked to the specified termset?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add below properties to map the column to a termset:

1. **SspId**- This is the GUID of managed metadata service
2. **TermSetId**- GUID of TermSet

Please try below schema:

```
<Field ID="{0AF6E300-E338-440F-90CB-726C11028EE1}"
  Type="Note"
 DisplayName="MyCompanyDocType_0"
 Name="MyCompanyDocTypeTaxHTField0"
 ShowInViewForms="FALSE"
Required="FALSE"
 Hidden="TRUE"
CanToggleHidden="TRUE" />

<Field ID="{F46BBB43-3E95-4AAA-A1AA-47EBC6B7DD0B}"
       Type="TaxonomyFieldType"
       DisplayName="MyCompanyDocType"
       ShowField="Term1033"
       Required="TRUE"
       Group="MyCompany"
       Name="MyCompanyDocType" >
  <Customization>
    <ArrayOfProperty>
      <Property>
        <Name>SspId</Name>
        <!--ID of the Managed metadata service -->
        <Value xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q1:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">2567ccb0-68f2-46f6-8f4f-36b0bb507422</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>TermSetId</Name>
        <!--ID of the Termset -->
        <Value xmlns:q2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q2:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">2cd1c0fb-88af-4066-a4fc-4c9734160eb5</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>TextField</Name>
        <!--ID of the Note field declared above -->
        <Value xmlns:q6="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q6:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">{0AF6E300-E338-440F-90CB-726C11028EE1}</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>IsPathRendered</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q7="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q7:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">true</Value>
      </Property>
    </ArrayOfProperty>
  </Customization>
</Field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a feature with the columns and contenttype elements files. Create an feature event receiver as follow:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            try
            {
                SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
                Guid fieldId = new Guid("{BA879CDD-D0A2-491A-AEF0-ED9AC6F83C4C}"); // custom managed metadata column
                if (site.RootWeb.Fields.Contains(fieldId))
                {
                    TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(site);

                    if (session.TermStores.Count != 0)
                    {
                        var termStore = session.DefaultKeywordsTermStore;

                        if (termStore != null)
                        {
                            var group = termStore.Groups["MyCustomTermGroupName"];
                            var termSet = group.TermSets["MyCustomTermSetName"];
                            TaxonomyField field = site.RootWeb.Fields[fieldId] as TaxonomyField;

                            // Connect to MMS 
                            field.SspId = termSet.TermStore.Id;
                            field.TermSetId = termSet.Id;
                            field.TargetTemplate = string.Empty;
                            field.AnchorId = Guid.Empty;
                            field.Update();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: This is over kill