# "taxid" crawled property not being generated from provisioned taxonomy field

Tags: search, taxonomy, refiner, crawled-property

I am trying to provision a few site columns to be used by a metadata term store. So far, I can CRUD list items and choose terms for each taxonomy field I have in my list.

Now I am trying to build a custom search page for my solution with a refiner web part that has a refiner for each of my taxonomy fields. For this, I go to `Central Administration -> Manage Service Applications -> Search Service Application -> Search Schema` and look up my crawled properties so I can map it to a managed property and reference that in turn in my refiner web part (I created at least one list item and did a full crawl before doing this). However, I only find one crawled property. Only the one `"ows_<Column_Name>"` is there, the other `"ows_taxId_<Column_Name>"` seems to have not been generated during the full crawl.

I am unsure why, I have already tried multiple naming schemes for the note field accompanying the taxonomy field, including:

1. Setting `StaticName` and `Name` properties of note field to GUID of taxonomy field
2. Setting `StaticName` and `Name` properties of note field to GUID of taxonomy field, replacing the first character with 'p' (I saw this in Sharepoint Manager after creating a test list with tax column from UI)
3. Setting `StaticName` and `Name` properties of note field to `<Column_Name>TaxHTField` of taxonomy field
4. Setting `StaticName` and `Name` properties of note field to `<Column_Name>TaxHTField0` of taxonomy field
5. Setting `StaticName` and `Name` properties of note field to `<Column_Name>_0` of taxonomy field

Needless to say, none of the above solved my issue. So I am currently out of solutions and become to supsect that something else is wrong.

Anyway, here is my Schema.xml of my list containing the tax fields (unecessary stuff removed for clarity):

```
<Field Name="PE6C254B595E4F4BB848871B5F86F104" ID="{C33BBE02-118A-48E0-8D9C-DE684D35956A}" Type="Note" ShowInViewForms="FALSE" Required="FALSE" Hidden="TRUE" />
<Field Name="UserDefined" ID="{DE6C254B-595E-4F4B-B848-871B5F86F104}" Type="TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti" ShowField="Term1031" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Version="1" Mult="TRUE" Sortable="FALSE">
<Customization>
  <ArrayOfProperty>
    <Property>
      <Name>TextField</Name>
      <Value xmlns:q6="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q6:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">{C33BBE02-118A-48E0-8D9C-DE684D35956A}</Value>
    </Property>
    <Property>
      <Name>SspId</Name>
    </Property>
    <Property>
      <Name>TermSetId</Name>
    </Property>
  </ArrayOfProperty>
</Customization>
</Field>
```

So can anyone see a problem why my tax field won't generated the taxId crawled property?

EDIT: This is hopefully the solution:

```
<Field Name="UserDefined" 
        StaticName="UserDefined"
        ID="{DE6C254B-595E-4F4B-B848-871B5F86F104}" 
        Type="TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti" 
        DisplayName="$Resources:Tags;" 
        ShowField="Term1031" 
        Required="FALSE" 
        EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" 
        Mult="TRUE" 
        Sortable="FALSE"
        ShowInDisplayForm="FALSE"
        ShowInEditForm="FALSE"
        ShowInNewForm="FALSE">
<Customization>
    <ArrayOfProperty>
    <Property>
        <Name>TextField</Name>
        <Value xmlns:q6="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q6:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">{C33BBE02-118A-48E0-8D9C-DE684D35956A}</Value>
    </Property>
    <Property>
        <Name>SspId</Name>
    </Property>
    <Property>
        <Name>TermSetId</Name>
    </Property>
    </ArrayOfProperty>
</Customization>
</Field>
<Field Name="UserDefinedTaxHTField0" 
    StaticName="UserDefinedTaxHTField0"
    ID="{C33BBE02-118A-48E0-8D9C-DE684D35956A}" 
    Type="Note" 
    DisplayName="$Resources:TagsHidden;" 
    ShowInViewForms="FALSE" 
    Required="FALSE" 
    Hidden="TRUE" />
```

Comment: Hello @LeonidasFett,
Did you found any solution for this? I am facing same issue

Comment: Hey @BharatKhunti, please take a look at my answer. I have no idea what I did to make this work. I can just give you the field definitions and hope that they work as they are. If it doesn't work, give me another comment here, I will try searching for some code behind stuff where I modify these fields.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in SharePoint 2013, and for me the solution was your option #3: setting `StaticName` and `Name` to `<Column_Name>TaxHTField` for the `Note` field. To give you an example, these are some of the attributes in Schema.xml:

```
<Field Type="Note" DisplayName="my_Field_0" StaticName="my_FieldTaxHTField" Name="my_FieldTaxHTField" ID="{bdf90102-5407-475a-ae73-ec0b8d712ff1}" />
<Field Type="TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti" DisplayName="My Field" StaticName="my_Field" Name="my_Field" List="Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList" ShowField="Term1033" ID="{d3d49415-d87a-4921-807b-6e508df9f207}" Mult="TRUE" ></Field>
```

Make sure to set the **SspId** and **TermSetId** (see similar question [How to set Termset on managed metadata field in XML?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159729/how-to-set-termset-on-managed-metadata-field-in-xml)), and also have some data in your field before running a full crawl. Hope this helps.